# Loading PDF in IFRAME mode in IE

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I just see that the loading overlay doesn't disappear in IE when i load a PDF file...

```
$.extend($.colorbox.settings, {
    transition: "none",
    opacity: 0.6,
    iframe: false,
    fastIframe: false,
    returnFocus: true,
    escKey: false,      // do not close when ESC is pressed
    overlayClose: false,    // do not close when overlay is clicked
    initialWidth : 872,
    initialHeight : 465,
    innerWidth : 872,
    innerHeight : 465});

$.colorbox({
    iframe: true,
    data: null, 
    href : 'myPDFurl',
    title : 'Load PDF in IFRAME',
    onComplete : function() {
        alert('document loaded !');
    }
});
```

The "document loaded !" message doesn't appear either.

Thanks in advance,

devyan

Comment: I've found a way to make onComplete work in IE changing "fasiframe" to TRUE, but the loading overlay don't work...

Comment: Resolved with $.colorbox.settings.fastIframe = true because the problematic things are not used (onComplete executed without waiting end of load and loading overlay not displayed)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
    $.colorbox({
        iframe: true,
        innerWidth:425, innerHeight:344,
        href : 'url',
        title : 'Load PDF in IFRAME',
        onComplete : function() {
            alert('document loaded !');
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/EcqJP/

Comment: IE9 but it's ok. IE cache problem (my js was not updated in IE)

Answer (score 0):

For me worked this:

```
    $('.cboxPDF').css('outline','none').colorbox({iframe: true,
    innerWidth:'80%', innerHeight:'80%',
    title : 'Title od PDF',
    onComplete : function() {
        console.log('document loaded !')}
    });
```